# Using SQLite in a Metro style app

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro

Does SQLite for WinRT support foreign key constraint ? Can you please guide me on this ? Thanks.

Comment: You might want to checkout the answers left to your other questions, if an answer is correct, accept it.  You of course don't have to but it helps get future questions answered.

Answer (score 0):

Let me preface that I have not tried this, however, these two references (on [sqlite.org](http://sqlite.org)) would indicate yes. If it's not working, provide some additional info as to what errors/behavior you are seeing.

> **SQLite version 3.7.13 adds support for WinRT and metro style
>   applications for Microsoft Windows 8**. The 3.7.13 release is coming
>   sooner than is usual after the previous release in order to get this
>   new capability into the hands of developers. To use SQLite in a metro
>   style application, compile with the -DSQLITE_OS_WINRT flag. Because of
>   the increased application security and safety requirements of WinRT,
>   all database filenames should be full pathnames. Note that SQLite is
>   not capable of accessing databases outside the installation directory
>   and application data directory. This restriction is another security
>   and safety feature of WinRT. **Apart from these restrictions, SQLite
>   should work exactly the same on WinRT as it does on every other
>   system**. ([2012-June-11](http://www.sqlite.org/news.html))

and

> [This document](http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html) describes the support for SQL foreign key constraints introduced in SQLite version **3.6.19**.

3.7.13 > 3.6.19

Answer (score 0):

SQLite supporting relationship constraints is one thing - the wrapper you'll use in your app supporting it is another.

I think there are today two drivers :

- [SQLite-net](https://code.google.com/p/sqlite-net/) : ORM style with object to DB mapping, LINQ support but NO FOREIGN KEYS support
- [sqlite-winrt](http://sqlwinrt.codeplex.com/) : Relationships constraints support, but you'll do everything by hand. Bascially, it supports connecting to a SQLite DB, executing queries and fetching results.

I'm looking for a better driver right now by the way, if someone knows one I'd be glad to know about it !

HTH